# How can I execute a exe file on client from the server? Nodejs

Tags: node.js, exe

I want to keep my executable on my server then on the client desktop It'll be another EXE file that they run and once it's ran It'll contain the address of the server that hosts the executable file then the executable file that is on the server will be ran on the client-side desktop.

I did some research and I have found nothing that can help me out. Can someone give me an code example or a guild to help me on this (In Nodejs.)

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming we're talking about a browser client (webpage running in a browser), then "no" you can't run an executable on the client from the server. That would open a gigantic security hole for web browsing if allowed.

If you're talking about a native code client running on the client's computer (an app the user downloaded to their computer and then ran), then you can do anything that the local OS allows you to do from the native code client (including downloading and running other executables).

Comment: Yes I am. How would I be able to host the native code on my server and then send a request to view it without directly sharing the source code with the client. Thanks.

Comment: @Ayden - "Yes I am" what?  I describe two scenarios.  You haven't clarified which one you're using.  The usual way you avoid downloading/installing code on the client is that you ask the server to do the work for you and send the result back to the client.  You don't say what this code does so we have no idea how to advise more specifically on that topic.